# Find the number of solution in $\sin^5 x+\cos^3x=1$ in $(0, 2\pi]$

Tags: functions

Find the number of solution in $\sin^5 x+\cos^3x=1$ in $(0, 2\pi]$.

My approach is as follow

I am using the concept

$T=\sin^5 x+\cos^3x-1$ in $(0, 2\pi]$

$T'=5\sin^4 x \cos x-3\cos^2x \sin x$

After this step I am not able to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a graph of $\sin^5 x + \cos^3 x - 1$ for $0 < x \leq 2 \pi$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$1=\sin^5 x+\cos^3x= \left| \sin^5 x+\cos^3x \right| \leq \left|\sin^5 x\right|+\left|\cos^3x\right| \leq \sin^2 x+ \cos^2x =1$$

This means that all inequalities must be equalities.

Comment: How does this help, and what do you mean? $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2x =1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @SteveKass If $1 \leq A \leq B \leq 1$ this means $A=B$. In this particular case, this mens $\sin^5(x)=\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^3(x)=\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: Although it's true that in this case, $\sin^5(x)=\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^3(x)=\cos^2(x)$, I don’t see why it follows from the fact that $A=B$, whichever sums you are considering as $A$ and $B$. The fact alone that two sums are equal to each other doesn’t allow one to conclude that the separate addends of the sums are equal.

Comment: @SteveKass If $c \leq d$ and $e \leq f$ and $c+e=d+f$ what can you say about $c$ and $e$? Note here that $\left|\sin^5 x\right|+\left|\cos^3x\right| \leq \sin^2 x+ \cos^2x $ is true because $$\left|\sin^5 x\right| \leq \sin^2 x\\\left|\cos^3x\right| \leq \cos^2x $$